# Firebase crash due to null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, websocket, firebase

Firebase null pointer exception. Attached stacktrace down below

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
       at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketHandshake.verifyServerHandshakeHeaders(WebSocketHandshake.java:96)
       at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(WebSocket.java:365)
       at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(WebSocket.java:30)
       at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(WebSocket.java:108)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Version : latest (2.5.2+) as of 3-may-2016

Device Details : LGE - lgls770 running android 6.0 and Non-Rooted

Comment: Does this happen consistently? Are you behind a proxy? This seems to occur when the right HTTP headers for upgrading to a WebSocket connection are not set.

Comment: I added firebase just yesterday and pushed update. It crashed for 1 user nearly 12 times.

Comment: Is the stack trace always the same? Do you have more information than just this stack trace? If so, can you share it (or reach out to firebase-support@google.com to share it)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added device details. May be this could help

Comment: have you found solution ?. I am facing same problem.

Comment: @SimpleCoder faced this when i used any firebase products before 1st activity onCreate (i.e in application class ...etc). Now i am not using firebase in application class moved all firebase related code to different module and using that in activities

Comment: In my case, this occurs soon after the publication of a new version, I believe during the tests done by Google (Nuage Laboratoire) for the pre-release report. After completing the tests, they do not occur anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The code snippet below is the implementation of `verifyServerhandshakeHeaders` method found in `WebSocketHandshake.java`.

```
public void verifyServerHandshakeHeaders(HashMap<String, String> headers) {
    if (!headers.get("Upgrade").toLowerCase(Locale.US).equals("websocket")) {
        throw new WebSocketException("connection failed: missing header field in server handshake: Upgrade");
    } else if (!headers.get("Connection").toLowerCase(Locale.US).equals("upgrade")) {
        throw new WebSocketException("connection failed: missing header field in server handshake: Connection");
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the server does not include an Upgrade HTTP header in the response of the *opening handshake* (RFC 6455, [4. Opening Handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4)), this code throws `NullPointerException`.

In addition, because the `headers` instance given to this method is created by `new HashMap<String, String>()` (`WebSocket.java:360`), HTTP headers sent from the server must be **case-sensitive** although the HTTP specification says *"Field names are **case-insensitive"*** (RFC 2616, [4.2 Message Headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2)). Therefore, for example, if a server sends an Upgrade HTTP header in all capital letters like `UPGRADE`, TubeSock throws `NullPointerException` although the server's behavior is correct.

`headers` instance should be created by

```
new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

as I pointed out at a certain place.

TubeSock's WebSocket implementation does not even verify `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header although the verification is required by RFC 6455. See RFC 6455, [4.1. Client Requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.1) for details.

Comment: you gave lot of information, but whsat is the solution

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the previous version of firebase then update your library version of firebase.

In my case i was using the the firebase analytics

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
```

Then I updated that with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
```

Everything is now working fine in my case.still if you have problem let me know.

if my answer will help you then don't forgot to increase my answer vote.